# Undefined error when attempt to setProps in enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm attempting to write tests with Enzyme, but every time I pass in the setProps method, I keep getting the error:     TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. This is confusing to me, because .map is being called on the props, which from my understanding are properly defined in the setProps function below. Why am I getting this error if I have setProps defined and how can I fix it?

```
beforeEach(() => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Map />);
})

describe('<Map />', () => {
    it('should render some stuff', () => {
        wrapper.setProps({ stories: [{id: 1, title: "hello world", edit: true}] })
    });
});
```

and the component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Map extends Component {

    state = {
        edit: true
    }

    render() {
        let layout = (
            <div>
                { this.props.stories.map((story, index) => {
                    return story.edit ? 
                    <div key={story.id}>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="text" defaultValue={story.title} ref="stuff2" /><button name="Save" onClick={this.props.handleToggle} value={story.id}>Save</button> 
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                    : 
                    <div key={story.id}>
                        <br/>
                        <div ref="1">{story.title}<button key={story.id} onClick={this.props.handleToggle} value={story.id}>Edit</button><button onClick={this.props.handleDelete}>Delete</button></div>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                 })}
            </div>
            )

        return (
            <div>
                {layout}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, check out how react works with enzyme, `this.props.stories` will be initially `undefined` because of how lifecycle works.

So before you use `setProps` in your test, nothing is passed as `stories` for initial rendering.

And componentWillMount, render will happen => render raises an error because you tries to iterate over undefined collection

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're calling `.map` on an array?  `props` is an object.  If you're trying to map over a prop that *is* an array, you'll need to make sure you're targeting it correctly

Comment: i figured it out. since this.props was being called in the render function and not the return statement, it was hitting that error with the before each hook